# i cannot download the python package neat

Tags: python, installation, download, package, neat

```
Collecting neat
  Using cached neat-0.4.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 

  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [1 lines of output]
  error in neat setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
  [end of output]
```

#this is my error(i have to add this to be able to post the error)
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

```
Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.
```

#this is my error

```
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

                  [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
                   [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Is this for node.js?

Comment: i figured it out to anyone wondering, i downloaded it and put the file in sitepackages